# How to check if CKEeditor is empty in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this code to get the content out of the body:

```
    $scope.editor.document.getBody().getHtml()
```

So how can I check if the text is empty when the only thing inside is a blank space ot the style?

`<body>&nbsp;</body>` or `<body><strong></strong></body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vanilla JS you could do something like this:

```js
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

function checkEmpty (element, resultElement) {

  let content = document.getElementById(element).innerHTML;
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");
  let isEmpty = doc.documentElement.textContent.trim() === '';
  document.getElementById(resultElement).innerHTML = element + ' is ' + (isEmpty ? 'empty' : 'full');
}

checkEmpty('is_empty', 'empty');
checkEmpty('is_full', 'full');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  height: 30px;
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
Element "is_empty":
<div id="is_empty">
<tag><empty>&nbsp;</empty></tag>
</div>

Element "is_full":
<div id="is_full">
<tag><empty>&nbsp;2</empty></tag>
</div>

<hr>
Result:
<div id="full">

</div>
<div id="empty">

</div>
```

The `DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html")` will remove the tags and invisible HTML elements so only the text contents will remain.

Comment: Thank you very much DOMParser was the solution, it works perfect

Comment: @labdev great to hear!